# Bounding hyperparameter optimization with Tensorflow bijector chain in GPflow 2.0

Tags: optimization, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability, gpflow

While doing GP regression in GPflow 2.0, I want to set hard bounds on lengthscale (i.e. limiting lengthscale optimization range). Following this thread ([Setting hyperparameter optimization bounds in GPflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903446/setting-hyperparameter-optimization-bounds-in-gpflow-2-0)), I constructed a TensorFlow Bijector chain (see `bounded_lengthscale` function below).  However, the bijector chain below does not prevent the model from optimizing outside the supposed bounds. What do I need to change to make the `bounded_lengthscale` function put hard bounds on optimization?

Below is the MRE:

```py
import gpflow 
import numpy as np
from gpflow.utilities import print_summary
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_probability import bijectors as tfb

# Noisy training data
noise = 0.3
X = np.arange(-3, 4, 1).reshape(-1, 1).astype('float64')
Y = (np.sin(X) + noise * np.random.randn(*X.shape)).reshape(-1,1)

def bounded_lengthscale(low, high, lengthscale):
    """Returns lengthscale Parameter with optimization bounds."""
    affine = tfb.AffineScalar(shift=low, scale=high-low)
    sigmoid = tfb.Sigmoid()
    logistic = tfb.Chain([affine, sigmoid])
    parameter = gpflow.Parameter(lengthscale, transform=logistic, dtype=tf.float32)
    parameter = tf.cast(parameter, dtype=tf.float64)
    return parameter

# build GPR model
k = gpflow.kernels.Matern52()
m = gpflow.models.GPR(data=(X, Y), kernel=k)

m.kernel.lengthscale.assign(bounded_lengthscale(0, 1, 0.5))

print_summary(m)

# train model
@tf.function(autograph=False)
def objective_closure():
    return - m.log_marginal_likelihood()

opt = gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()
opt_logs = opt.minimize(objective_closure,
                        m.trainable_variables)
print_summary(m)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Version 0.8.0 of tensorflow_probability does not have the Shift/Scale bijectors, instead you need to use `Affine` or `AffineScalar` (with `shift=` and `scale=` arguments).

Comment: @STJ, You are right.  When running the AffineScalar bijector I the following warning:   WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-3-6b076a3937d1>:4: AffineScalar.__init__ (from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.affine_scalar) is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
`AffineScalar` bijector is deprecated; please use `tfb.Shift(loc)(tfb.Scale(...))` instead. 
Is that implying that a future version of tensorflow_probability will have the Shift/Scale bijectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tfb.Sigmoid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/bijectors/Sigmoid) now accepts `low` and `high` parameters, as @Brian Patton forecasted in a comment.

Therefore, the code can be simplified to :

```
from tensorflow_probability import bijectors as tfb

def bounded_lengthscale(low, high, lengthscale):
    """Make lengthscale tfp Parameter with optimization bounds."""
    sigmoid = tfb.Sigmoid(low, high)
    parameter = gpflow.Parameter(lengthscale, transform=sigmoid, dtype='float32')
    return parameter

m.kernel.lengthscale = bounded_lengthscale(0, 1, 0.5)
```

Comment: Beware, you may need to cast `low`, `high`  values and `dtype` parameter to double for tensorflow.

Answer (score 3):

In the MWE you `assign` a new **value** to a `Parameter` that is already existing (and does not have the logistic transform). This value is the constrained-space value that the Parameter constructed with logistic transform has, but the transform isn't carried over. Instead, you need to **replace** the Parameter without logistic transform with one with the transform you want: `m.kernel.lengthscale = bounded_lengthscale(0,1,0.5)`.

Note that the object that you assign to the `kernel.lengthscale` attribute **must** be a `Parameter` instance; if you assign the return value of `tf.cast(parameter)` as in the MWE this is equivalent to a constant, and it won't actually be optimised!

Simply temoving the tf.cast in the MWE in this question won't immediately work due to float32/float64 mismatch. To fix it, the AffineScalar bijector needs to be in float64; it does not have a `dtype` argument, instead cast the arguments to `shift=` and `scale=` to the required type:

```py
def bounded_lengthscale(low, high, lengthscale):
    """Make lengthscale tfp Parameter with optimization bounds."""
    affine = tfb.AffineScalar(shift=tf.cast(low, tf.float64),
                              scale=tf.cast(high-low, tf.float64))
    sigmoid = tfb.Sigmoid()
    logistic = tfb.Chain([affine, sigmoid])
    parameter = gpflow.Parameter(lengthscale, transform=logistic, dtype=tf.float64)
    return parameter

m.kernel.lengthscale = bounded_lengthscale(0, 1, 0.5)
```

(GPflow should probably contain a helper function like this to make bounded parameter transforms easier to use - GPflow always appreciates people helping out, so if you want to turn this into a pull request, please do!)

Comment: may there be stars in your crown.  This is extremely helpful and solves my problem.  Thank you.  I've never submitted a pull request but am open to it.  Where would you recommend the helper function be added in the GPflow source code?

Comment: @Rcameron in [gpflow.utilities.bijectors](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/gpflow/utilities/bijectors.py), which already has `positive` and `triangular` utilities.

Comment: FYI we have a change going into `tfb.Sigmoid` soon that will allow you to provide `low` and `high` parameters and do this with better numerical stability.